# Inquiry regarding error while deploying GCP Anthos sample

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-anthos

We followed the guide below to deploy the anthos sample.
https://cloud.google.com/anthos/docs/tutorials/explore-anthos?hl=ko#before-you-begin
I am posting a question because an error occurred while distributing the anthos sample provided by GCP.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQtSV.png)

While deploying the 'anthos-config-management-setup' part of the anthos components, an error like the image occurred and I don't know how to resolve it.

https://cloud.google.com/anthos/docs/tutorials/troubleshooting?hl=ko

The guide says to delete the project and then redeploy it, but the same error occurs even after repeating it several times.
I also changed regions and availability zones.What should I do?